# Detecting Keypoint of 3D model, and distance between them

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I am very new to AI, I have a set of 3D human models that I would like to train the algorithm to identify wrist, upper arm, lower arms, etc, and distance between them.

From my understanding, this is a regression problem. But with my very limited knowledge, most tutorial online showing me cat and dog classification problem.

Do you have any clue for me to research next? There are some paper saying to convert the 3D model to image, and use convolutional neural network for training.

p/s: Please don't downvote me, I am too young and too lost in this field.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format of your 3D model dataset , if your dataset is made of cad models you could voxelize your dataset and train a convolutional neural network on it , but it could be very time consuming to train 3D convnets . instead you could use a multi view 2D CNN https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00880?context=cs